# Reducedness of complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a very general surface of degree $\ge 5$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $ Y$ is arbitrary irreducible cubic hypersurface. Is $X \cap Y$ reduced ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes (of course, $Y$ should be reduced). Since $X$ is very general we may assume $\operatorname{Pic}(X)=\mathbb{Z}\cdot [\mathscr{O}_X(1)]$. If the divisor $Y_{|X}$ on $X$ is not reduced, it is of the form  $2H+H'$, where $H$ and $H'$ are hyperplane sections  of $X$ (possibly equal). But since the restriction map $H^0(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(3))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathscr{O}_X(3))$ is injective, this implies that $Y$ is non reduced.

Comment: Do we need $Y$ to be reduced  or irreducible is enough ?

Comment: If $Y$ is not reduced, there is no chance that $Y\cap X$ is reduced.